# How to install "cordova-plugin-whitelist" from command line

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, plugman

I am following [Phonegap official tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/develop/1-embed-webview/android/). I have downloaded Phonegap android base project and now I am trying to add plugins to `"Hello World"` app but it's throwing below error

Command line error:

```
D:\cordova-android-master\bin\HybridAndroidApp>plugman install --platform android --project . --
plugin cordova-plugin-device
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-device':CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater at D:\cordova-android-master\bin\HybridAndroidApp\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:278:19
```

I have updated JDK to 1.8 also set it in System Environment variable

Comment: fire command for installing whitelist plugin throuigh command : **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist**

Comment: From where I should fire the above command...

Comment: please follow this https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/ then you will get to know. it's cordova one whovh is realted to phonegap also

Comment: Check PATH settings for both System Variables and User variables. I was able to fix this issue by setting both values to correct jdk1.8.0_101 path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some problem in [cordova-android base project](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android) I have followed steps from [this link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html) And I am able to add plugins.

Comment: I can confirm that running "cordova requirements" will help identify the missing dependencies.  In my case, I didn't have the right Android SDK version installed for the version of the platform I was trying to use.