# Keep getting: Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, cordova, cmd, sdk

I'm new to this and I just wanted to do the things in this Tutorial:

[Installing Cordova & Android SDK on Windows 7, 8 & 10 to Develop Mobile app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atH7naB4fDk)

At 7:36 it's shown that I have to type:`cordova platform add android`

I did it but I'm getting this:

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (G:\Cordovatest\hello\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Hope to get some help-

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994309/how-to-install-cordova-plugin-whitelist-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

please do the following:

1) Add the environment variables, `ANDROID_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` ( giving the path of the folder `Android SDK` and the one of `JDK` in the value).

2) In the `System Variable PATH`, add the `path` of the `platform-tools` the one of the `Tools` folder.

It will fix your error successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Case Ionic Solution plugin fail whitelisterror

1. invoking the location of the java_home executable ie java.exe then recompiling

reason: the environment variables did not load at that time fail windows, because if they were well declare, Thanks