# Ubuntu 16/Cordova 6.4/Android: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ubuntu, gradle

I'm trying to use Cordova 6.4 with Android Studio in Ubuntu 16 OS.

I've installed the Android Studio Correctly and downloads the SDK.

And the npm and cordova is also installed.

---

And I tried to create a project:

```
cordova create myapp
cd myapp
cordova platform add android
```

And this yields the following error:

```
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms/android
        Package: io.cordova.hellocordova
        Name: HelloCordova
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-24
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.0.0
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android
ANDROID_HOME=/home/alfred/Android/Sdk/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Subproject Path: CordovaLib

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.847 secs
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: /home/alfred/app/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/home/alfred/app/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: /home/alfred/app/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
```

And if I run `cordova run android` after that, it still tells the block of `Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.` error.

The same thing seemed not happening under windows.

I've search around the web with no luck. Anyone knows how?

Comment: Hello Alfred Huang, you need to install the cordova-plugin-whitelist, so try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994309/how-to-install-cordova-plugin-whitelist-from-command-line

Comment: @Jaco thank you, but did not help in my situation.

Comment: This article gives a useful thread, but not worked around yet: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6362#issuecomment-262684912

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below article tells how to import a ssl certificate of a secific site to java environment.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6362#issuecomment-262684912

---

#### Step 1 : Download the certificate

Download this file.

Or the same on Mozilla Firefox :

Go to https://repo1.maven.org

- Click on the green padlock at the left of adress bar.
- Click on Details.
- Click on View certificate.
- Click on Details.
- Click on Export.
- Export file to "X.509 Certificate (PEM) (*.crt; *.pem)"

#### Step 2 : Add the certificate to default java keystore

```
sudo keytool -import -alias MavenRepo -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file /PATH/TO/YOUR/EXPORTED/FILE.crt
```

Your `$JAVA_HOME` variable is normally declared in your `.bashrc` file, so you can use this command just replacing the `/PATH/TO/YOUR/EXPORTED/FILE` parameter.

> PS : The default password of java keystore is : changeit

---

It get the procedure a bit forward, but still not solved.

Finally I solved the problem by reinstall the OS.

It seemed it is not relavent with ubuntu or linux itself, codova and android studio worked well in ubuntu after I reinstall the OS.